# Which ctx should I use in run parameter of hystrix.Do function of hystrix-go package? The ctx from upper level, or context.Background()?

Tags: go

Which `ctx` should I use in `run` parameter of `hystrix.Do` function of `hystrix-go` package? The `ctx` from the upper level, or context.Background()?
Thanks.

```
package main

import(
    "context"

    "github.com/myteksi/hystrix-go/hystrix"
)

func tb(ctx context.Context)error{
    return nil
}

func ta(ctx context.Context){
    hystrix.Do("cbName", func()error{
        // At this place, the ctx parameter of function tb,
        // Should I use ctx from ta function, or context.Background()?
        return tb(ctx)
    }, nil)
}


func main(){
    ta(context.Background())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using contexts, it seems to me like you should using `hystrix.DoC`. There's no reason to use anything than whatever context passed through, since `Do` is synchronous, and you would like whatever cancellations, deadlines (and whatever else is attached to your context) to be preserved inside this code.

```
func ta(ctx context.Context) {
    err := hystrix.DoC(ctx, "cbName", func(ctx context.Context) error {
       ... code that uses ctx here.
    }, nil)
    // handle err, which may be a hystrix error.
}
```

It's hard to say if this is actually different from calling `hystrix.Do`, but this potentially allows hystrix to use your context, to add deadlines/cancellations itself.

Comment: This does help you inject context to test your function though, so that's a plus

Answer (score 1):

Always use the `context.Context` coming from the upper level as a parameter wherever you can. It allows an end to end mechanism to control request, all the caller has to do is cancel, or invoke timeout on the initial `ctx`, and it will work for the complete request path.

The initial context passed can depend on your requirement. If you're not sure about what context to use initially, [context.TODO](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#TODO) can be a good option till you're sure.